# Force browser to use specific Accept field in HTTP request

Tags: html, http, web, mime-types

is it possible to enforce a web browser to use specific mime-type in html request?

`<a type="application/pdf" href="https://url.com/">PDF</a>` or `<a type="text/html" href="https://url.com/">HTML</a>` so here browser requests both times with text/html in accept field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time you can control request headers is when the request is being made with XMLHttpRequest or Fetch.

This problem is better solved by having distinct URLs.

E.g.

```
<a href=“http://example.com/example.pdf”>PDF</a>
<a href=“http://example.com/example”>HTML</a>
```

Comment: the problem is that I cannot control URL as it is fixed on a QR code